# PSEXEC Passing commands and using IF loop

Tags: batch-file, psexec, wmic

When I run my batch file to go through a huge pile of IPs and get some info IF if can connect to the remote cmd, it does not work.

If it cannot connect the `echo` does not work, and if it does connect, it opens the remote command shell and does nothing until I exit back to the local command shell.

```
cd \pstools

psexec.exe @C:\users\chargraves\desktop\inv.txt cmd /c

if errorlevel 0 (
wmic csproduct get version >> \\path\results.txt &
)

if errorlevel 1(
echo "Not accessible"
)
```

I also started trying powershell.  But as soon as it gets into a remote command shell, it just hangs.  IT doesn't input the wmic code..."

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\users\chargraves\Desktop\inv.txt    
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        & "c:\pstools\psexec.exe" \\$computer "cmd"
        & "wmic csproduct get version >> \\share\results.txt"
    }
```

Comment: There is an orphaned `&` sign after `results.txt` which needs to be removed. There is a _space_ missing: `if errorlevel 1 (`. Are you aware that the `if errorlevel #` syntax means _if errorlevel is equal or greater than #_? to do an equal-to comparison, use the syntax `if %errorlevel% equ #` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to works successfully and is much less complicated.  Thank you.

Batch 1

```
cd \pstools
psexec.exe @iplist.txt -c batch2.bat
```

Batch 2

```
wmic command 1 >> results.txt
wmic command 2 >> results.txt
wmic command 3 >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
cd \pstools

psexec.exe @C:\users\chargraves\desktop\inv.txt cmd /c

if %errorlevel%==1 goto fail

REM if errorlevel is 0 then it executes these lines
wmic csproduct get version >> \\path\results.txt

:fail
REM if errorlevel is 1 then it executes the lines bellow
echo "Not Accesible"
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
```